# Is it possible to object to (and revert) an edit that was made to my question?

Tags: support, moderation, editing

A user has made edits to my question which I find objectionable. It's [edit #3 here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/117252/revisions).

The changes:

- replace "filmmakers" with "film makers"
- replace "&" with "and"
- replace two straight ASCII quotes with UTF-8 angle quotes

I also notice this user has voted to close the question, and has made two comments challenging its validity on Movies.SE.

Given that, and the plain fact that their edits don't make any attempt to make my question less objectionable according to their stated criteria, I frankly resent having this user's name listed next to mine. And I stand by my right to use the words and punctuation that I put into the original question.

I would like to know if it's possible to revert their edit.

Answer (score 5):

It's your question, you have the ability to edit it all you like, either rolling back edits or making new ones.

However, I have to state that this is a co-operatively edited site and it's the norm for people to edit other people's content.  I understand being concerned about close votes, but I wouldn't automatically dismiss legitimate edits just because they came from the same person. In general we discourage 'edit wars' where people argue over versions of the same content, minor or otherwise.

It's an interesting question and has attracted good answers and lots of upvotes.  I wouldn't be too fussed about someone's (legitimate) concerns that it might be too opinion based for example.

[These edits are trivially minor, and none would be a hill I would personally die on. The only one I feel is an improvement is the removal of ampersand (&) which ideally would be used in names or to clarify lists of items, and not just a substitute for 'and'.  That's my personal opinion.]

Comment: I believe the guidance given to users is not to make pointless edits like the ones I described. An edit should "significantly" improve a post [src](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Do you disagree? Or is it your position that these edits _are_ a substantial improvement?

Comment: No, I agree with you @Tom - but if this were me, I would ask myself whether it is worth getting upset about that.

Comment: That is good advice. I don't intend to die angry about it. At the same time, I don't want to see someone rewarded for taking 2 dumps on my post and then also changing the style of my writing. My post was not unclear, nor was it in violation any house style guide.

Comment: @Tom I would really advise you to not equate edits (however insignificant you deem them yourself) or genuine concerns about the question's appropriateness (however much you agree with these concerns) as "taking a dump". This is an *immensely* inappropriate interpretation and doesn't really help *anyone* involved. It frankly doesn't make the intentions behind this meta question stand in the most favourable light. It's also unclear to me, in which way the editors and/or close-voters of your question are "rewarded" in any sense or how having their names next to yours is *remotely* a problem.

Comment: @Tom To put it in a bluntness I feel your tone and phasing makes somewhat necessary, I'd say you kind of need to...get over yourself here.

Comment: @Tom Why did you revert my edit? Why are you so insistent on using "&" when "and" is the correct word to use? Also, the movie is called ***The** Princess Bride*, not *Princess Bride*. Plus the title of a question is not the first line of a question, it is the title.